# Limit on API calls

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, rate-limiting

There is some API limits on how many calls I can make per min and per day. IS there some way to with `request` lib to control this limits and in case I'm reaching to per minute limit it will sleep for some time and then continue?

> Minutely limit - your app can make 60 API calls per
> minute. Daily limit - your app can make 5,000 API calls,
> per day.

[image: response type]

If the API limit it reached 429 is the response code

```
import requests

for url in list_of_endpoints:
    url=url
    headers ={
        'Authorization' : f'Bearer {store_new_access_token[0]}'
             }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=retries#example-automatic-retries

Comment: Coul you please explain little bit more?